# How to enumerate all string keys in locale domain?

Tags: php, localization, locale, gettext

Translated strings for our program are stored on a server in .po/.mo files.
We need to export translations to XML.
It seems that the natural way is to write a small PHP script that prints strings in tags like this

```
<s key="apple" value="яблоко"/>
<s key="orange" value="апельсин"/>
```

It is easy when you know all the keys in .po/.mo files.
Set domain, set locale and use gettext().

But I have not found a function to enumerate all strings in the domain.
The only option I can think of is to list all translation keys manually to get the job done.
I'm too lazy for this job.

Is there a way to enumerate all translation keys in the domain?

Comment: I would search for thing like "parse po file". I bet tons of scripts exist.

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. We're not in the 1990s any more.

Answer (score 1):

`.mo` files are binary files which, as far as I know, don't actually store the `msgid`, but rather a version of it that's easily accessible, in an index.

`.po` files are simple text files which list all `msgid`s, easy to parse with a regex like `#msgid "([^"]+)#`